# Navbar and Sidebar at the same time using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This may seem a bit silly but I want to implement this sidebar: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/ with http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav (the navbar navbar-default example).

What would be the best way to combine both? Or should I look into another package for a sidebar? I'm using Angular if that makes any difference.

Since I can't post images... look at my comment to see what it currently looks like.

Comment: Right now... this is what my screen looks like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IYIhZ.png

Comment: try making a jsfiddle for your question

Comment: You can push the sidebar down so that its below the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with Bootstrap and CSS. No need for another package. Just set the percentage (ie: 40%) you want the sidebar to push the main content when activated:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -40%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 40%;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 12px;
  }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/ppK9PJ4i5f